# Regex or another way to extract full URLs + relative URLs from HTML

Tags: c#, regex, parsing, html-parsing

So I have a SharePoint site and I have users who submit new items into a SharePoint List. Some fields in the list item contain URLs that reference files or images, e.g. `"http://host/abc.jpg"` or `"/abc.jpg"`.

In another field, users edit HTML code which may contain any tags such as `<a href="/abc.jpg">`, `<img src="/abc.jpg">` and so on.

**My goal** is to find fields that contain links/URLs, and extract those URLs that point to something that has a filename plus extension. I have no problem extracting this from the SharePoint fields which may contain either some irrelevant information or the URL (and the URL only) using these two regexes:

```
//this will match full url e.g. http://localhost/path/a.jpg
var fullUrlRegex = 
            new Regex(@"^https?:\/\/(?:.*)[\.]+(?:[a-z0-9]{1,4})$");
//this will match an absolute path like //test/files to upload/222.jpg
var absolutePathRegex =
            new Regex(@"^\/.*[\.]+(?:[a-z0-9]{1,4})$");

var fullUrlRegexMatch = fullUrlRegex.Match(value);
var absolutePathRegexMatch = absolutePathRegex.Match(value);

//now check which one matched and save the value
```

However, I am not sure how to approach extracting URLs (both relative and full URLs) from HTML code that users enter in the other field.

Suppose this is the user's input, and I need to extract both links to files from that HTML code.

```
<p>This is a <a href="/abc.jpg">picture</a>! 
And this is a pic too: <img src="/abc.jpg"></p>
```

The tags can really be anything, not just limited to `<a>` and `<img>`. One way I thought I could approach this is to use HTML Agility Pack, but this seems like an overkill. Would it be sufficient to regex-search for `src="(match this)"` and `href="(match this)"`? Anything I might miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regexes should not contain ^ at the start and $ at the end. It is an achor. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx.

Also use **Matches** method to get all matches.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex

```
(?<=(href="|src="))[/]*(?:[A-Za-z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=:@]|%[0-9a-fA-F]{2})*(?:/(?:[A-Za-z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=:@]|%[0-9a-fA-F]{2})*)*
```

Just add any other valid tags to the list in (href="|src=")